# Google Sheets apply conditionnal formatting for each column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'd like to highlight the max value in each column. Example :

```
   A    B    C
1  50   12   60%
2  20   84   50% 
3  38   20   15%
```

Here A1, B2, C1 will be highlighted. So I know how to do that for 1 column. I create a custom formula :

```
=$A:$A=max(A:A)
```

So if I do that, only the A1 cell will be highlighted. So how can I do that for the other column at the same time without duplicate conditionnal formatting on each column ?

*I noticed that the max() function not working on percentage, it doesn't highlight my cell, do you know why ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional formatting with the following custom formula: `=B2=MAX(B$2:B$4)`. Change the cell names to suit your use case. `B2` indicates the first cell in the selection and `B$2:B$4` is first column in this example.

[image]

[Source](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2105-excel-highlight-largest-lowest-value-in-row-column.html)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much :)